# form's get method vs angular $http.get request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, get

I want to make a get request to a specific url through my angular frontend to the expressjs backend, now in my frontend if I do :-

```
 <li>
      <a ng-click="givequiz()">GiveQuiz</a> 
 </li>
```

and my angular code is:-

```
$scope.givequiz=function(){
    console.log("give quiz");
    $http.get('/home/givequiz').then(function(res){
      //request is going fine and all
});
}
```

The above thing is working but I am getting the response as an object, the complete file and url isn't changing and all.

But if i do the form get thing :-

```
<li>
       <form action="http://localhost:8000/home/givequiz" method="GET">
          <button type="submit">Give Quiz</button>
       </form> 
</li>
```

this takes me to a new url called "http://localhost:8000/home/givequiz"
 but the $http.get doesn't why is this so? Aren't both methods same? And that's how I am handling both the requests.

```
router.get('/givequiz', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("in getquiz");
//always gets printed ^ means all reqs come here
    res.sendFile('/givequiz.html',{ root: client });
});
      Any help will be much appreciated.
```

Comment: At first case you should change route manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your code is working fine. Angular is making an AJAX type request behind the scenes. If you want to change route when the response comes back successfully you should do:

```
$http.get('/home/givequiz').then(function(res){
    // request is going fine and all
    $state.go(nameOfState)
});
```

You could alternatively set `window.location` in the then resolve block but that will prob cause a page refresh whereas `state.go` should not.

Comment: Why is it that the form's get scene redirects to the "givequiz" and ajax get just sends that page as a response?

Comment: Previously in the web world you had to reload the page to make a request. In the new world you can make a request behind the scenes. This is called an AJAX request. This is when you don't want to reload the page but just want to get some more info from the server. Angular is making an AJAX type request for info. When it resolves your code tells it what to do next. Given that Angular can change state without refreshing the page this is a useful thing in the Angular world.

Comment: How exactly can I then send an Ajax request and get the new page instead of getting it as a response?

Comment: with Ajax requests you dont tend to request new HTML pages from the server. You tend to request information, for example, a customer list or something. If you want to change state in angular just do something like ... $state.go('/home/givequiz') or if you dont mind a page refresh ... window.location = fullDomain + '/home/givequiz'